# google sheet and IF with "#N\D" value

Tags: google-sheets

I'm importing some data with importXML into a google sheet, but I need to have another ImportXML (with different regexp) when the first display "#N\D". I have tried with if.error but nothing, same with if IMPORTXML(....)="#N\D".
What Can I do?
thx

Comment: Add the formula that you tried.

Comment: =IF(IMPORTXML(meta!B1; "//*[@title='atto'][1]/div[2]/div[4]/a/@href")="#N\D";IMPORTXML(meta!B1; "//*[@title='atto'][1]/div[2]/div[3]/a/@href"))

Comment: Please edit your question to include the formula on it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
IMPORTXML(meta!B1; "//*[@title='atto'][1]/div[2]/div[4]/a/@href")="#N\D"
```

try

```
ISERROR(IMPORTXML(meta!B1; "//*[@title='atto'][1]/div[2]/div[4]/a/@href"))
```

or

```
IMPORTXML(meta!B1; "//*[@title='atto'][1]/div[2]/div[4]/a/@href")=NA()
```